# Subquery of two related tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to write the following query in Laravel 5.

```
SELECT *
FROM loans
WHERE loanAmount > (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(paidLoanAmount), 0)
                    FROM paid_loans WHERE loanId = loans.id);
```

I have tried the following, but subquery of PaidLoan seems not work due to loans.id or something else I don't notice.

```
Loan::where(
    'loanAmount', 
    '<=', 
    PaidLoan::where('paid_loans.loanId', 'loans.id')
        ->get()
        ->sum('paidLoanAmount')
)->get();
```

Comment: Have you started by creating a `Loan` model using Laravel's Eloquent models? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: Loan::where('loanAmount', '<=', PaidLoan::where('paid_loans.loanId', 'loans.id')->get()->sum('paidLoanAmount'))->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use a leftJoin on the loan and just add a normal condition.

```
$payedLoans = Loan::leftJoin('paid_loans', 'paid_loans.loanId', '=', 'loans.id')
    ->where('loanAmount', '<=', \DB::raw("IFNULL(sum('paid_loans.paidLoanAmount'), 0)"))
    ->groupBy('loans.id')
    ->get();
```